# How to create a 3D shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How can I create a 3D shapefile containing line features or point features?
I have to extract the elevations from a DEM and then export a shapefile containing 3D features.
I'm currently working with QGIS 2.8.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it in different ways to create a 3D shape files (which have the 3D geometry, vertex coordinates of X, Y, Z):
with DTM (DEM):

1. to processing v.drape (GRASS GIS);
2. using the plugin shp2D3 (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shp2D3-master/)

v.drape
[image: Processing]

shp2D3
[image: plugin]

Comment: is there any risk of losing the Z coordinate with usual commands/operations (e.g copy/paste 3D features, join CSV file by attribute...)?

Comment: the two methods described modifying the geometry and not the attributes;
you can do all the operations, also joins.

NOTE: To copy / paste is only valid on shapefile with 3D geometry.